# make-frame does not set the right font size

Tags: emacs, fonts, emacs-faces

If I open up a new frame in emacs (v24.3.1), the font is set to a different size. All other settings are correct but the fontsize. (On the screenshot, the window in the back opens up a new frame with `make-frame`, the window in the front is the new window, with the wrong font size.

[image]

In my init.el, I have the following code:

```
 (set-face-font 'default "-misc-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed--13-120-75-75-c-60-iso8859-1")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your init file (and any code it loads) for something that changes `default-frame-alist`, specifically with respect to parameter `font` or `font-parameter`. Check the definition of face `default`.

You can customize option `default-frame-alist` or face `default`, to control this. (But you still might want to figure out what code you are using already changes this.)

```
 M-x customize-face default
 M-x customize-option default-frame-alist
```

**Always, for something like this, please report whether the behavior you observe happens also when you start from `emacs -Q`, that is, without your init file.**

If it does *not*, then recursively bisect your init file (by commenting-out 1/2, then 3/4, then 7/8,... until you find the culprit code that is causing the problem. This is a binary search, so it is very quick (though it does not seem so at the outset).

(Your screenshot indicates that you have Projectile loaded, for example. We cannot help you debug something if it is just a giant sack of stuff, all or most of which is unknown to us. You need to narrow things down, to identify what is causing the problem - by bisecting your init file.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've updated my question with the line which causes the problem. Can I put this on a place every frame can use it?

Comment: Instead of using `set-face-font`, just customize option `default-frame-alist` so that parameter `font` has that value. Or customize face `default`.